# How to install Google Font on nodejs-canvas?

Tags: node.js, canvas

I'm trying to get Google Fonts dynamically with nodejs-canvas and I'm not sure what is the best way to do that.
I understand it needs to be with: "registerFont" method.
This is the code I have now:

```
const { registerFont, createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
//registerFont('comicsans.ttf', { family: 'Comic Sans' })
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let name = req.query.name;

// Write "Awesome!"
ctx.font = '30px Impact'
ctx.rotate(0.1)
ctx.fillText(name, 50, 100)

// Draw line under text
var text = ctx.measureText(name)
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.lineTo(50, 102)
ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102)
ctx.stroke()

//console.log(canvas.toDataURL());

res.write('<img style="border:1px solid #000;" src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
res.end();
```

Answer (score 5):

Using PT Mono as an example this is how you do it.

1. First go to the font directly in this case [PT Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Mono).
2. Next click the "download family" link in the top right. That will give you a zip file which contains the TTF font.
3. Now copy the ttf file into your node application directory and use `registerFont` in your file like this.

`registerFont('PtMono-Regular.ttf', { family: 'PT Mono' });`

As per the documentation make sure you register your fonts *before* creating the canvas.

Then to use your font on your canvas you'd just use the following to set the font for the  context.

`ctx.font = "16px 'PT Mono'";`

Full Example using our google font just modifying the original example in the [node-canvs repo](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#registerfont).

```
const { registerFont, createCanvas } = require('canvas');
registerFont('PtMono-Regular.ttf', { family: 'PT Mono' });

const canvas = createCanvas(500, 500);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = `16px "PT Mono"`;
ctx.fillText('This is the font.', 250, 10);
```